# Replacing PHP.ini as ec2-user with FileZilla

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm logging in to my server with my `ec2-user` account (using FileZilla). I want to replae the `PHP.ini` that is in the `/etc` folder with a pre-made file of my own.

The thing is I don't have permissions to do so and I can't figure a way to replace this file.

I can't login with the root to FileZilla (is there a way to do it?) and I'm not sure if I can use `sudo` as part of the FileZilla application.

I tried to `chown` the whole `/etc` folder under ecw-user, but that endedup with me getting `/etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 500 should be 0` message for every command I'm trying to do.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the permission just to the `PHP.ini` and not the whole etc directory using:

```
sudo chown ec2-user <file_name>
```

This enabled me to replace the file.

Comment: You may have broken other things by blindly changing permissions within `/etc`.  Don't do that.  I would recommend scrapping that instance and starting over, because you may find problems later... it's even possible that your next reboot will not succeed.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Can I give root the permissions that I took?

Comment: You can try.  That may not get you back to 100% correct but should be better that nothing.